# CodeIgniter Authentication Libraries with user confirmation by admin

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, confirm

I'm looking for a CodeIgniter Authentication Libraries so I can confirm user registration by admin role (not by sending confirmation email). Can anyone give me a suggestion ? Thanks alot.

Comment: No matter which one you choose, you should be expecting to modify it somewhat to suite your specific requirements. CI framework and the CI classes you find online are not complete solutions... they are just  starting points.  I really prefer Ion Auth myself, but again I needed to make some modifications for my application.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is the best thing I can get.

Answer (score 0):

No matter which one you choose, you should be expecting to modify it somewhat to suite your specific requirements. CI framework and the CI classes you find online are not complete solutions... they are just starting points. I really prefer [Ion Auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) myself, but again I needed to make some modifications for my application.